# MUI Select Component Padding (ReactJS)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI `Select` component and am trying to reduce the padding within the element. The padding appears to be a property of one of the subclasses `.MuiOutlinedInput-input`. However, I haven't been able to change the padding despite setting it to zero using the standard `sx` approach.

**Edit**: I was able to find a working solution, see my post in the solutions thread.

Here is the base code for the component:

```
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';

<Select
  id="time-period-select"
  value={timeline}
  onChange={handleTimelineChange}
  variant="outlined"
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>All Time</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>This Year</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>This Month</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={40}>This Week</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={50}>Today</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Here is my attempt to remove the padding (I have tried several variations of this):

```
<Select
  ...
  sx={p: 0, '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {p: 0}}
>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

***Side Note***:
I would like to further customize the component (ex. changing the background color) which doesn't seem to work either, so if you have a general approach for customizing the `Select` component that would be great :)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change the global css, you could overwrite children of a given element like so:

```
<Select
 sx={{
   '& .MuiSelect-select': {
      paddingRight: 4,
      paddingLeft: 2,
      paddingTop: 1,
      paddingBottom: 1,
   }
 }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around some more and looking at [MUI Treasury](https://mui-treasury.com), I was able to arrive at a solution. The following is the correct approach:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  select: {
    background: '#F5F6F9',
    paddingLeft: 24,
    paddingTop: 14,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    ...
  },
}));

...

const classes = useStyles();

<Select
  ...
  disableUnderline
  classes={{ root: classes.select }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and tried all possible way but the best way i have found is go to the root which means override the css for this we have to find class name which causes padding for this i have checked the component by the developer option(browser) there i found the class name, then i overridden the css.for this firstly i have copied the class name,then in the global.css or any css file(which is responsible for styling of the react component ) used it and written my own padding parameter.
like:

```css
/** next js global.css*/ 
.css-11u53oe-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input.css-11u53oe-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input.css-11u53oe-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

hope it helps,check this image i ve attached[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OawYh.jpg)